# Custom DateTime format in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have ASP.NET MVC Create View.

This view have binded ViewModel which contains two DateTime objects:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime When { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Until { get; set; }
```

I'm binding it to DatePickers like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.When, new { @class = "form-control ui-datepicker-my" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Until, new { @class = "form-control ui-datepicker-my" })
```

And datepickers are configured like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function()
    {
        $(".ui-datepicker-my").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Problem is that when I'm POSTing form, my model is not valid. I mean date '22-02-2014' is being converted in wrong format (It's trying to read '22' as month)

**I do not want to mess with global culture.**

How to do it?

I have tried editing it like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.When,"{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control ui-datepicker-my" })
```

But without progress

Comment: You either need to set the server culture so that it matches that format, or create a custom model binder.

Comment: Sadly, you're going to hit a whole load of problems with dates unless you lock down the culture setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on not setting the culture for the app/page (it's gonna bite you).  You can use this:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(inputedDateString, formatOfInput, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
```

so something like

```
DateTime myDate  = DateTime.MinValue;
string valueFromForm = "22-02-2014";
DateTime.TryParseExact(valueFromForm , "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
```

Comment: I'll go with changing culture info. If everybody says this is good, I belive.